# Find the position of the object when the velocity is 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

The position of an object given by $f(t)=5t^2-6t+13$ where $t$ is measured in seconds and the position is measured in meters.  Find the position of the object when the velocity is 0.

I'm confused on this problem. Am I suppose to use derivatives on this problem? And where do I plug in my 0 at?

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The velocity is the derivative of the position with respect to time, which is $f\,'(t)$. Once you have that function, you set it to $0$ and solve for $t$ to find the **time** at which the velocity is zero, and then you can use that time to find the **position** of the object at that moment.

Comment: Good afternoon Brian, what do mathematicians really mean when they say things like "let the variable $t$ be time" or, as another example, "let the variable $x$ be position" ? I'm assuming we're being a little informal here and using mathematics to model something in the real world by *denoting* it with a symbol (such as the presumably real variable $t$ for *time*), but I wanted your feedback regardless. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, that’s what’s going on. Sometimes you’ll see a more careful statement, for instance like this: *Let* $t$ *be the time in seconds after the ball is thrown*.

Comment: I definitely prefer the more careful statement! Additionally, I thought about my question a little more after your feedback and was wondering if the statement "let the variable $t$ be time" could also be interpreted as: $t$ is a placeholder for a real number that has units in seconds?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: I wouldn’t put it that way, since it’s not holding a place for a specific number; it seems to me much better to use language that makes it clear that $t$ is a variable. Note too that you can’t assume that time is measured in seconds: depending on context it might be measured in nanoseconds or centuries!

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for pointing that out. With that said, would it be better to go with my first explanation since we're merely *thinking* of $t$ as being time? Additionally, instead of defining a variable as a sort of placeholder, should I be defining it as a symbol for any mathematical object?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Even just in mathematics the noun *variable* has [quite a variety of meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(mathematics)); I’m not at all sure that a really good concise general definition is possible.

Comment: I have been seeing other mathematicians point that out too. My last question regarding this thread is: do you think my first explanation would still make sense if I replaced the word *model* with *represent* so that the sentence reads "...using mathematics to represent something in the real world by denoting it with a symbol..."?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes; in fact, I think that I prefer that version.

Comment: Good afternoon once again, Brian! Sorry to revive this thread of questions, but I have one more regarding wording: I've been reading about [mathematical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model) recently and was wondering if a function could be a mathematical model of a real world phenomenon? The reason for my question is I have noticed authors define a mathematical model as *a description of a system using mathematical concepts and language* and I was curious if just a function fits this definition (as opposed to a set of functions, or system of equations, etc.).

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, if you include verbiage relating the entities in the function to the real world phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Use them rules from mechanics.
Differential of distance -->Velocity(in m/s)
Differential of velocity-->Acceleration(m/s^2)
 Differential of accelaration-->Jerk(m/s^3).

So differentiate distance w.r.t time to get velocity. then equate that to zero and solve for t. Take that time t and substitute it back into the distance equation to get the distance.

So ds/dt = 10t - 6 
equate that to 0 making it 0=10t - 6 and solve for t to get something like 6/10 seconds. take that 6/10 and substitute it into the function given for distance which is f(x)=5t^2 -6t +13 to get the distance in metres